# Magento2: How can We add multiple customer billing address?

Tags: magento2, billing-address

I want to add multiple customer billing address and fetch all customer billing address programmatically.

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only set 1 default billing address within magento but you can add additional addresses to get the customers address's you can do this by using Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory and with implimenting the below code

```
$customer = $this->_customerRepository->getById($customerId);
$addresses = $customer->getAddresses(); // Returns Array
```

Comment: Issue is resolved. thanks!